# Screen not loading when trying to navigate between screens

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, react-navigation

I'm trying to navigate between 7 screens in react native and when I load my code the screens show up blank. I don't know if there's a problem inside my app.js file or whether it's in the login screen file. I'm trying to create a social media app with react native which should in turn navigate between all of these screens without any errors.

My App.js file is:

```
import home from "./screens/home";
import explore from "./screens/explore";
import createpost from "./screens/createpost";
import messages from "./screens/messages";
import profile from "./screens/profile";
import settings from "./screens/settings";
import login from "./screens/login";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
    return (
       <NavigationContainer>
         <Stack.Navigator>
           <Stack.Screen 
              name="login"
              component={login}
              options={{title: "Welcome"}}
           />
           <Stack.Screen
              name="home"
              component={home}
            />
         </Stack.Navigator>
       </NavigationContainer>
    );
    }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

My login screen file is:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function login() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button title="Navigate to second screen with french"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("explore", { language: "french"})}
            />
            <Button title="Navigate to second screen with english"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("explore", { language: "french"})}
            />
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>

    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that the screen is showing something, I mean, the explore screen, does it have the correct styling? Maybe it's working, but it's not visible because of the styles. If something is wrong beacuse of the navigation, you should get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the pages you want to
navigate to in your stack as you did with login and home.

```
<Stack.Navigator>
       <Stack.Screen 
          name="login"
          component={login}
          options={{title: "Welcome"}}
       />
       <Stack.Screen
          name="home"
          component={home}
        />
       <Stack.Screen
          name="explore"
          component={explore}
        />
        ...
   </Stack.Navigator>
```

Then

```
navigation.navigate('explore', {...});
```

should work.

Comment: What file do I add navigation.navigate to?

Comment: You already call navigate function in your buttons onPress prop

Comment: I added the extra screens to the stack but it still showed a blank page on the expo

Comment: Can you post your code for explore page?